# Dynamically create and remove NSWindow

Tags: swift, macos, nswindow

I'd like to create (and destroy) NSWindows programmatically

```swift
class Wins: NSObject, NSWindowDelegate {

    var windows = Set<NSWindow>()

    func createWindow() {
        
        let newWindow = NSWindow(contentRect: .init(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: 300, height: 300)),
                                 styleMask: NSWindow.StyleMask(rawValue: 0xf),
                                 backing: .buffered,
                                 defer: false)
        newWindow.title = "New Window"
        newWindow.isOpaque = false
        newWindow.isMovableByWindowBackground = true

        newWindow.backgroundColor = NSColor(calibratedHue: 0, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 0, alpha: 0.7)
        newWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)

        let windowController = NSWindowController()
        windowController.window = newWindow

        windows.insert(newWindow)
    }

    func closeAll() {
        for win in windows {
            windows.remove(win)
            win.close()
        }
    }

}
```

Although the code above works, the closed windows are never deallocated and keep piling up in the memory.

If I remove the `windowController` assignment, the app crashes when I try to close the windows with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, and using the profiler, I can see the window was actually deallocated:

`An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated 'NSWindow' object (zombie) at address...`

So I believe the `windowController` instance is the culprit and is never being destroyed.

How can I implement a proper NSWindow lifecycle for programmatically created windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deallocation of `NSWindow` is a bit complicated for historical reasons. From the documentation of `NSWindow.close()`:

> If the window is set to be released when closed, a release message is sent to the object after the current event is completed. For an NSWindow object, the default is to be released on closing, while for an NSPanel object, the default is not to be released. You can use the isReleasedWhenClosed property to change the default behavior.

From the documentation of `isReleasedWhenClosed`:

> The value of this property is true if the window is automatically released after being closed; false if it’s simply removed from the screen.

The default for NSWindow is true; the default for NSPanel is false. Release when closed, however, is ignored for windows owned by window controllers. Another strategy for releasing an NSWindow object is to have its delegate autorelease it on receiving a windowShouldClose(_:) message.

If you own the window then `isReleasedWhenClosed` should be `false` and the window controller can be removed.

```
func createWindow() {
    
    let newWindow = NSWindow(contentRect: .init(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: 300, height: 300)),
                             styleMask: NSWindow.StyleMask(rawValue: 0xf),
                             backing: .buffered,
                             defer: false)
    newWindow.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
    newWindow.title = "New Window"
    newWindow.isOpaque = false
    newWindow.isMovableByWindowBackground = true

    newWindow.backgroundColor = NSColor(calibratedHue: 0, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 0, alpha: 0.7)
    newWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)

    windows.insert(newWindow)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @willeke. But setting `isReleasedWhenClosed` to false will have essentially the same effect as keeping the `windowController`: the windows are never released. Also, I believe I can't use autorelease when on ARC, right?

Comment: The windows are released in my test app. Do you close the windows in `closeAll` or manually?

Comment: I tried both, manually closing or calling `closeAll`, I even tried changing from `win.close()` to `win.performClose(win)`, but running it from the profiler I can see that the memory is only going up and never released when the windows are closed. 
But isn't that the expected behavior when `isReleasedWhenClosed` is set to `false`? Or how can the window be released?

Comment: When `isReleasedWhenClosed` is `true` then `close` calls `release`. This is very handy when ARC is off and there isn't a strong reference to the window. When ARC is on then `windows.remove(win)` calls `release`. Is the window removed from `windows`?

Comment: Yes, the reference is removed from the Set. The problem is that if I don't set `isReleasedWhenClosed` to false, the app crashes when a window is closed. But when it's false, I can see the memory usage increase for every open/close window cycle, so I assume the windows are still there, just not visible.
I tested this by opening many windows and closing them multiple times. Every time I do this I see the memory increase and never be freed.
How can I assert if the NSWindows are actually being released or check what is piling up in the memory? (my whole code is what I shared, no other processes)

Comment: Check the number of `NSWindow`s in [Instruments](https://help.apple.com/instruments/mac/current/#/dev022f987b) or set a breakpoint on `-[NSWindow dealloc]`.

Comment: thanks for all the help. Although I still see the issue with some of the memory not being released, the initial question about the window lifecycle is answered and I'm marking this as accepted.
Using the instruments, I can see that the NSWindows are indeed being released, but something else is leaving allocations behind, I believe it is some internals happening after `win.close` to blame.